# When specifying an NFS mountpoint in /etc/fstab, What is the "addr" option for?

Tags: nfs

When specifying an NFS mountpoint in /etc/fstab, what's the purpose of the addr option? For example:

```
192.168.1.5:/home         /home                   nfs     rw,addr=192.168.1.5 0 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can specify the client address to use when the client has multiple subnet IPs on an interface and traversing the same routes (think aliased eth0:1, bond0:2, etc.). Typically in this situation you'd put the NFS server on another interface/subnet to avoid the whole problem but in large network installations things can get messy.

Answer (score 2):

`addr` is not the same as `clientaddr`. The `addr` option is what the NFS server /etc/exports explicitly specifies, e.g.

```
 /home 192.168.1.5 (rw)
```

instead of simply

```
 /home * (rw)
```

If the NFS server has multiple interfaces, you can designate a specific interface for the NFS traffic. Of course if you do leave it to the server to choose an interface (i.e. specify *), the server chooses one out of the available IPs and you see it in the client side `mount' command output.

(in response to troyengel's answer)
The clientaddr mount option is for the server to callback the client for certain metadata, not data. I think this includes verifying whether the client is allowed to mount, etc.

`addr` is a server IP. `clientaddr` is a client IP.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the man page for mount (http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount). It appears as though that option is accepted but ignored. I could not find any other information on it.

Comment: I suspect it is to be used for multi-homed installations; so that you can specify which IP address local to the server to use as a source.

E.g. run the NFS traffic over an internal network, rather than a public interface.

Answer (score 0):

I believe NFS uses it internally, you see it in `/proc/mounts` even when not specified.